# Why does a fraction of my Angular2 template keep re-rendering even if there are no changes?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 component that renders page fragments based on data coming from a headless CMS. In particular, the component renders a page footer using a template like this:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6" *ngFor="let column of footer">
             <div [innerHtml]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(column)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where `this.footer` is a private variable containing an array of HTML strings. `this.footer` is set in `ngOnInit()`. The whole template is much larger than this.

My problem is that this particular fragment of the template **keeps re-rendering every 1-2 seconds**. This makes it impossible to select contact details that are found in the footer, since the selected HTML nodes are replaced by new (identical) ones and the selection thus gets reset.

The rest of the page is rendered in a similar way, but it is not exhibiting this problem. If I look at the elements in the Chrome debugger I can see the `<div>s` of this particular fragment flash as they are replaced.

I am logging `ngOnInit()` and `ngOnChanges()` but they are not getting run during this re-rendering.

I am at loss as to what is causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bind to functions in the view then they are called every time change detection runs.

If `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(column)` returns a different object instance for every call, Angular renders the `[innerHTML]` part again because it recognizes it as change.

Prefer assigning the function result to a property in your component and bind to this property to the view instead.

Comment: Mmm.... that was a nice little trap. Obviously the function result is a different instance even if the argument is the same. Thx.

Comment: That's usually the case, except when the result is cached and the function returns a cached result. But in this case you could just bind to the cache and only get the function called when an argument has changed.